# Suppress WHERE clause if is passed Zero or Nothing in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working with `CakePHP 3.0` and created a `query` for your `ORM`, this `query` is working perfectly but now I need if a particular parameter is **0** or **nothing** is passed to the method the **where** clause is deleted.

**Method that creates the query to the ORM**

```
public function listProductsByTrend($subCategoryId, $productsQuantity, $column, $order) 
{ 
$products = TableRegistry::get('products'); 
$query = $products->find(); 
$query->select(['product_name', 'quantity', 'sold', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'thumbnail']) 
->where(['sub_category_id' => $subCategoryId]) 
->order([$column => $order]) 
->limit($productsQuantity); 
return $query; 
}
```

If $subCategoryId is **0** or **nothing** the **where** clause should be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No secret. Just strip the logic like this:

```
public function listProductsByTrend($subCategoryId, $productsQuantity, $column, $order)
{
    $products = TableRegistry::get('products');
    $query = $products->find();
    $query = $query->select(['product_name', 'quantity', 'sold', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'thumbnail']);
    if ($subCategoryId > 0) {
        $query = $query->where(['sub_category_id' => $subCategoryId]);
    }

    return $query->order([$column => $order])->limit($productsQuantity);
}
```